# How can I make pyinstaller look at a home dir based config file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

#### TLDR

To make my question a little bit clearer, I am not trying to bundle the config file with pyinstaller. This is because the app will create it if it does not exist. What I am trying to do is to have the pyinstaller compiled binary to read the config file if it already exists.

I am trying to use pyinstaller on a small project that uses a configparser based ini file to load certain variables. When my project in installed with pip and on first run, it will look for and if does not exist, create the necessary config files in the home dir. This applies to windows, osx and linux.

The issue that I am having is that when I compile the project with pyinstaller, it does not look for this.

My question is, how can i compile my project so that it looks at the specified location for the config file at runtime? Preferably with the `onefile` option. My project is [here](https://github.com/securisec/chepy).

For example, in my config file, I have a config object called pluginpath. If i run my pip installed project, then the pluginpath is read from the home based config file, and a path is printed (if i added a new value to it). But if i run it from the compiled binary, then it prints `None` which is the default value.

My spec generated onefile spec file

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['cli.py'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='chepy',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

Answer (score 0):

### Updated answer

I think change your original code

```py
home = Path.home()
self.chepy_dir = (
    Path(".chepy").resolve()
    if Path(".chepy").exists()
    else Path(home / ".chepy")
)
self.chepy_conf = Path(self.chepy_dir / "chepy.conf")
```

to this will works

```
home = Path.home()
self.chepy_dir = (
    Path(home / ".chepy").resolve()
    if Path(home / ".chepy").exists()
    else Path(home / ".chepy")
)
self.chepy_conf = Path(self.chepy_dir / "chepy.conf")
```

With `home` in two `Path`, it will look `.chepy` in user home directory other than the folder where `chepy/chepy/config.py` lies in, that is `chepy/chepy`.

### Original answer

I think you are talking about read configure file in run-time. The related `pyinstaller` docs is here. [run-time-information](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html)

You don't need to change `spec` file but you need to notice **the file path of you want to read when run-time** and **the path where you execute the bundled app**.

For example, you have a example.py:

```
with open('a.txt') as f:
        print(f.read())
```

When you compiled, it will read `a.txt` in the folder **where you execute the command**.

After `pyinstaller example.py`, the file structure looks like this:

```
--
 - example.py
 - dist/
   - example/
     - ...
     - example.exe
```

If you run `.\dist\example\example.exe` in current directory, the bundled app will look for `a.txt` in current directory.

If you run `.\example\example.exe` in `dist` folder, the bundled app will look for `a.txt` in `dist`folder.

Comment: Thanks! But is isnt exactly my issue. The way the config files are read is by resolving absolute config file path from `pathlib.Path`. So my issue is that the compiled app is not really reading that context. You can see [here](https://github.com/securisec/chepy/blob/master/chepy/config.py#L13-L19) how the config file is being read.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, there is a reason why I wrote my code that way. If a user wants to use a temporary conf file which is in the PWD from where the app is run, then `Path(".chepy").resolve()` handles that. Thats why setting `Path(home / ".chepy").resolve()` would break that functionality, because it will only work on the home dir folder then. The app behavior is, if conf file in pwd, then use conf file. else check for conf file in home dir, and use it if it exists, or create one if one doesnt. Because with path, I can get the CWD context.